# Get Type Annotations In Python 3.7

Tags: python, python-3.x, types

I would like to simply access the type annotations that I've declared in my class definition's `__init__` method:

```
class Cls:
    def __init__(self, data: dict)
        pass

def get_type(function):
    # What goes here?

cls = Cls({})

get_type(cls.__init__) # Returns 'dict' type.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import inspect

def get_type(function):
    print(inspect.formatargspec(*inspect.getfullargspec(function)))
```

will print `(self, data: dict)`.

Comment: "formatargspec is not defined" error when running in the python 3.7 shell. edit: just saw the edit trying it now

Comment: Sorry, had to impoty `inspect` is this better?

Comment: Yep! More straight forward than my initial solution using the inspect module as well. nice.

Comment: This will also return the types etc. for all parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `inspect` modules `getmembers` function: https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html

It returns a list of members for whatever object you pass. If you pass a function, it will include a two-tuple where the first element is `'__annotations__'` and the second element is a dictionary that maps the parameter name to type annotation. Currently (Python 3.7) the `getmembers` function will return the `'__annotations__'` tuple as the first element, so the following will work:

```
import inspect

class Cls:
    def __init__(self, data: dict)
        pass

def get_type(function, param_name):
    return inspect.getmembers(function)[0][1][param_name]

cls = Cls({})

get_type(cls.__init__, 'data') # Returns dict
```